# How to fix "RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Importing keras failed on macOS 10.14.4 failed with the error:

> ```
> RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.6 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.7
> ```

Comment: How did you install TensorFlow through source as per the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source . Also make sure you're installing keras in your virtual env

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

And I solved my problem by update my tensorflow:

```
conda update tensorflow
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: So first of all, my tensorflow was installed automatically by keras. The version of tensorflow was v1.13.1 which is newest in anaconda cloud. But I met the same problem Runtime warning. After using conda update tensorflow, the version does not change but it did fix the bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am setting up my environment (Mac OsX 10.14.4) based on [this tutorial on machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/setup-python-environment-machine-learning-deep-learning-anaconda/), and when I first ran the deep_versions.py (prints versions of theano, tensorflow, and keras) I got the same RuntimeWarning as OP describes. It looks like the version that got installed when I ran:

```sh
$ conda install theano
...
$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

installed a version of tensorflow that was compiled using Python 3.6. I found [this GitHub issue comment from August 2018](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21472#issuecomment-412130935) that claims they don't have (at the time) a native binary for Python 3.7 yet.

Based on [AKAWei's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56042910/6520477) I ran:

```sh
$ conda update tensorflow
```

and that got rid of the RuntimeWarning.